# Java scrollbar not visible

Tags: java, scrollpane

I am new to java. I am trying to implement scroll feature to my Jpanel but the schoolpane is not visible. I tried to many methods but nothing works.

```
public class test extends ContentPanel {

JPanel secondary;
JPanel customerType;
JPanel primary;


JPanel labelPanel;
JLabel lCustNo;
JLabel lCustName;
JLabel lTelNo;
JLabel lAddress;
JLabel lNationality;
JLabel lResident;
JLabel lVisitor;
JLabel lCustomerType;
JLabel lIdCard;
JLabel lBankName;
JLabel lPassportNo;
JLabel lVisitStart;
JLabel lVisitEnd;

JTextField tCustNo;
JTextField tCustName;
JTextField tTelNo;
JTextField tAddress;
JTextField tNationality;
JTextField tIdCard;
JTextField tBankName;
JTextField tPassportNo;
JTextField tVisitStart;
JTextField tVisitEnd;

JPanel radioButton;

JRadioButton rResident;
JRadioButton rVisitor;
ButtonGroup custType;

JScrollPane scrollBar;

JSeparator s1;
public test (String title, JPanel parent) {
    super(title, parent);
    secondary = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,0));
    secondary.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 800);
    labelPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2,300,20));
    radioButton = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4));
    customerType = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,4, 30, 20));
    primary = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    lCustNo = new JLabel("Customer No: ");
    lCustName = new JLabel("Name: ");
    lTelNo = new JLabel("Telephone Number: ");
    lAddress = new JLabel("Address: ");
    lNationality = new JLabel("Nationality: ");
    lResident = new JLabel("Resident");
    lVisitor = new JLabel("Visitor");
    lCustomerType = new JLabel("Customer Type");
    lIdCard = new JLabel("Id Card");
    lBankName = new JLabel("Bank Name");
    lPassportNo = new JLabel("Passport Number");
    lVisitStart = new JLabel("Visit Start");
    lVisitEnd = new JLabel("Visit End");
    tCustNo = new JTextField(10);
    tCustName = new JTextField(10);
    tTelNo = new JTextField(10);
    tAddress = new JTextField(10);
    tNationality = new JTextField(10);
    tIdCard = new JTextField(10);
    tBankName = new JTextField(10);
    tPassportNo = new JTextField(10);
    tVisitStart = new JTextField(10);
    tVisitEnd = new JTextField(10);
    rResident = new JRadioButton();
    rVisitor = new JRadioButton();
    custType = new ButtonGroup();
    customerType.add(lPassportNo);
    customerType.add(tPassportNo);
    customerType.add(lVisitStart);
    customerType.add(tVisitStart);
    customerType.add(lIdCard);
    customerType.add(tIdCard);
    customerType.add(lBankName);
    customerType.add(tBankName);
    customerType.add(lVisitEnd);
    customerType.add(tVisitEnd);

    custType.add(rResident);
    custType.add(rVisitor);

    radioButton.add(lVisitor);
    radioButton.add(rVisitor);
    radioButton.add(lResident);
    radioButton.add(rResident);

    labelPanel.add(lCustNo);
    labelPanel.add(tCustNo);
    labelPanel.add(lCustName);
    labelPanel.add(tCustName);
    labelPanel.add(lTelNo);
    labelPanel.add(tTelNo);
    labelPanel.add(lAddress);
    labelPanel.add(tAddress);
    labelPanel.add(lNationality);
    labelPanel.add(tNationality);

    secondary.add(customerType);
    secondary.add(labelPanel);;
    primary.add(secondary,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    scrollBar= new JScrollPane(primary);
    scrollBar.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 555);
    this.add(scrollBar);

}

}
```

My code is above. This class extends `contentPanel` and `contentPanel` extends `JPanel`. Someone please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to do an awful lot all at once. Your final app might look like this but when you run into trouble it's a good idea to isolate the problem. Try this: create a separate project with a simple panel and add a single scroll pane to it. See if it works and play around with it if it doesn't. Also, put some text into the pane. It's entirely possible you're not seeing scroll bars because they're not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `scrollBar` is not visible because it is not necessary. If you change `JScrollPane` settings, for example:

```
scrollBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
scrollBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

you will see you have it, but not use it. It is because your `scrollBar` doesn't have a content which expands dynamically (like `JTextArea` for example). Your `scrollBar` has `JPanel` inside, which has size to fit all its components, so it will not be enough to add some text inside text components.

To make scroll bars visible, you can change a size of `JSrollPane`. However  `setBound()` will not work if you `JPanel` use default `FlowLayout`. To use absolute positioning  in `JPanel` you need to use `null` layout, what is generally not recommended and is seen as bad programming practice.

Try to delete `setBound()` lines and use for example `scrollBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,555));` instead. You should see a difference.